# seating correctly

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 6 girls who are assigned 6 places to sit in a classroom. In how many ways can they be seated so at most 1 girl is in the correct place?

How do you  even start with this? My teacher didn't explained but I didn't understand a thing. Please help.

Comment: Start by drawing a circular table with 6 places and think about it

Comment: Why circular? What's the idea?

Comment: Use the principle of inclusion and exclusion @jay

Comment: It's not important for it to be circular, but I think that way you get a nicer drawing ;-)

Comment: I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Given $6$ girls and $6$ places for each girl to sit we want to count all the ways the $6$ girls can sit in the classroom where at most $1$ girl is in their natural position. This is a [derangement problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). First we count all the ways in which no girl is in their natural position, so $D_6$. Now we choose $1$ of the girls out of the $6$ girls, we can do this in ${6\choose 1}$ ways. The remaining $5$ girls must be seated such that none of them are in their natural position, so $D_5$. Thus the number of ways to seat $6$ girls where at most $1$ of the girls is in their natural position is $D_6+{6\choose 1}D_5$.